# Difference of means hypothesis test with geometric mean and geometric standard deviation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean, geometric-mean

I have some distributions which are only reported by their geometric mean, geometric standard deviation, and their sample size n (all output by closed box scientific software) - is it possible to use this information alone to do a statistical test like a t-test like in the way you can with the arithmetic mean / stdev / n for each distribution?